# EINTR and epoll_ctl, should I check errno?

Tags: c, linux, signals, epoll, kevent

I am looking through code for FreeBSD. The code uses `kevent` programming interface. Now, I find the lines like below:

```
status = kevent(...)
if(status < 0){
 if(EINTR == errno){
  goto l_kevent;
 }
 /* ... */
}
```

I need to port the code for Linux, and I wonder... Should I check for `EINTR` with Linux `epoll` calls. I know that `epoll` has `epoll_pwait`, and it is still should be checked for `EINTR`. But the documentation I have on hand tells me nothing about the `epoll_ctl` calls being interruptible.

I can look into source code for epoll. But, as humble, as I am, I do not know how signals are handled in kernel. So, if the code itself relies on some interrupt mechanics, I do not know where to look for return codes of interest.

Hope I explained problem. The question, once again: my documentation tell me nothing on `epoll_ctl` being interruptible, what should I do? Should I check for `EINTR`?

P.S
If someone will point me out for the source code for the epoll, that I can comprehend, I will gladly try to do my own research.

Comment: `epoll_ctl()` doesn't potentially block waiting for something, so afaik it can't be interrupted by a signal. The man page doesn't list `EINTR` as a possible error code for it...

Comment: @Shawn Your logic makes sense. I was confused by FreeBSD code. Maybe I should close the question. Now I see that it is really as you suggested.

Comment: @user14063792468, `kevent()` is a dual-use interface: it serves both to register interest in one or more events *and* to return events to the caller.  It potentially blocks when retrieving events, which is the analogue of `epoll_wait()`, but the documentation specifies that it *does not* block otherwise, which would include when operating strictly analogously to `epoll_ctl()`.  The docs are also fairly clear with respect to `EINTR` specifically, that it indicates termination due to a signal prior to timeout or queueing any events *to return*.